# Simulating a kCGEventOtherMouseDown only works for right-clicking

Tags: c++, macos, mouseevent, simulate, quartz

The following code for right-clicking works:

```
auto event = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(nullptr, kCGEventOtherMouseDown,
                                     {x, y}, kCGMouseButtonRight);
CGEventSetIntegerValueField(event, kCGMouseEventClickState, 1);
CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, event);
CFRelease(event);
```

however, the exact same code with `kCGMouseButtonRight` replaced with `kCGMouseButtonLeft` doesn't.

Sidenote: I have wondered if this is due to the latter event not registering, so I tried [a "Key Test"](https://en.key-test.ru) and found out that both events register as the middle-button(although the right-click works as expected for other applications).

Why does the left-click not work and how can I make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using `kCGEventLeftMouseDown` instead of `kCGEventOtherMouseDown`. This goes in hand with the [Apple documentation of `kCGEventOtherMouseDown`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgeventtype/kcgeventothermousedown?changes=_11&language=objc):

```
Specifies a mouse down event with one of buttons 2-31.
```

(left = 0, right = 1, center = 2, extra buttons = 3-31)

This also explains why the website registered left & right as center, but it does not explain why the right-click still worked(opened the context menu), but I guess that's what you gotta deal with when not looking at the docs properly.